# Cannot execute as the server principal... with Windows (Active Directory) Group login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm running SQL Server 2012 (I know, ancient...) and trying to work out why users don't have permission to execute some procedures.

I'm logged in as `sa`, just in case my own id doesn't have sufficient authority to impersonate.

When I try:

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'MBA\SAHFOS_GRP'
```

I get the message:

```
Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "MBA\SAHFOS_GRP" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.
```

As far as I can tell, it meets the requirements:

```
select * from sys.server_principals where name = 'MBA\SAHFOS_GRP'

name    principal_id    sid type    type_desc   is_disabled create_date modify_date default_database_name   default_language_name   credential_id   owning_principal_id is_fixed_role
MBA\SAHFOS_GRP  413 0x0105000000000005150000007CEB240DCD7C4166235F636BC8040000  G   WINDOWS_GROUP   0   2017-12-01 10:00:45.050 2017-12-01 10:00:45.057 cpr_prod    us_english  NULL    NULL    0
```

I'm `sa`, so surely I have permission. It exists. Which only leaves "cannot be impersonated". Why can't it be impersonated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not supported by design.

Ref: [EXECUTE AS Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Specifies the statements inside the module execute in the context of
> the user specified in user_name. Permissions for any objects within
> the module are verified against user_name. user_name cannot be
> specified for DDL triggers with server scope or logon triggers. Use
> login_name instead.
>
> user_name must exist in the current database and must be a singleton
> account. **user_name cannot be a group**, role, certificate, key, or
> built-in account, such as NT AUTHORITY\LocalService, NT
> AUTHORITY\NetworkService, or NT AUTHORITY\LocalSystem.

There are [workarounds](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-impersonate-an-ad-login-within-a-ad-group-defined-in-sql#:%7E:text=First%2C%20you%20can%20impersonate%20another,will%20run%20under%20their%20credentials.) you can use.

Comment: Ah, carp... I read that three or more times, still didn't actually get it :) I don't actually need a workaround, as I'm actually trying to figure out why users who are part of the group aren't getting the correct permissions. So, I was starting by trying to ensure that the group account had the correct authority.

Comment: Just pick one of the user instead of the group in your "execute as" and this will work

Comment: Sorry, @SqlWorldWide. I clicked the wrong button (well, it deserved an up-vote _too_, but I really did mean to accept it).

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher Well, yes, I knew that worked. But I was thinking there must be something wrong with the group membership, so trying to check that the group itself had permission. I was doing it all wrong :( [and I should have trusted that the inheritance via a group really did work, or I'd have found questions about _that_!]

Comment: with EXEC xp_logininfo 'loginname', you can see from which group the user gets its access. Then, you can validate the permission set on those group (specially if you use "deny" cause the permission cumulate if you are part of many groups). I hope this will help you